# Laravel - Can't pass data through view

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade

I try to send data from a controller to a view on Laravel 5.4.

My controller "PagesController.php" :

```
public function bird($id) {

    $infoBirdById = new InfoBird();
    $birdById = $infoBirdById->getBirdById($id);

    $infoHealthById = new InfoHealth();
    $healthById = $infoHealthById->getHealthById($id);

    $infoTransportByIdBird = new InfoTransport();
    $transportByIdBird = $infoTransportByIdBird->getTransportByIdBird($id);

    $infoUserByIdHealer = new InfoUser();
    $userByIdHealer = $infoUserByIdHealer->getUserByIdHealer($id);

    var_dump($userByIdHealer);
    //var_dump($birdById);
    //var_dump($healthById);
    //var_dump($transportByIdBird);

    return view('pages.bird', compact('birdById', 'healthById', 'userByIdHealer', 'transportByIdBird'));
}
```

An extract of the view "bird.blade.php" :

```
<div class="block block-name">
    <h2>{{ $userByIdHealer->prenom }} {{ $userByIdHealer->nom }}</h2>
</div>
```

Here is the error : Property [prenom] does not exist on this collection instance.

The resultant of the dump of userByIdhealer :

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[216]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[223]
          public 'id_biodiv_acteur' => int 3
          public 'nom' => string 'Rinaire' (length=7)
          public 'prenom' => string 'Vété' (length=6)
          public 'civilite' => string 'Homme' (length=5)
          public 'date_naissance' => string '2017-05-10' (length=10)
          ect...
```

So I don't understand why I have this error, because in the dump I can see that "prenom" is here...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Show your getUserByIdHealer($id); method

Comment: `prenom` is not a function or attribute on `Collection`. Since `$userByIdHealer` is a `Collection`, you need to loop it, or use `->first()` to get the first instance, then you should be able to use `->prenom` to access that attribute.

Comment: @Tim Lewis got it! And if your reaching many items in a collection just use `->get()` instead of `->first()`.

Comment: Correct, a `QueryBuilder` instance will return a `Collection` if the `closure` used is `->get()`, or a `Model` (usually) if used with `->first()`. Also, a `Collection` also has the function `->first()` to return a single `Model`. Otherwise, treat a `Collection` like an array with additional functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ $userByIdHealer[0]->prenom }} {{ $userByIdHealer[0]->nom }}
```

you are getting it inside 0 array so use this or you can loop with foreach and use without 0

Comment: Just be aware that this will throw a `trying to property of non-object` if `$userByIdHealer[0]` isn't set; should always check with `isset(...)` before trying to access.